# jQuery Validation will hide error container even if server message message is present, how to prevent this?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

Using the [jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) package.

Checking login fields after a failed login in attempt. The error container has a message which states the failed reason. Credentials do not match.

- Enter a bad email format: ie. te
- Remove focus by pressing tab, the error message of bad format appears for the email.
- complete this field, test@test.test, press tab
- Error messages disappear.
- Enter 1 character and press tab
- Server Message and Error Message of Password is not 8 characters appears.

Maybe I am being picky, but I would like for the server error to remain visible. Having it disappear and reappear is bothersome to me. How is this possible?

I was reading about using `invalidHandler` function, but since I have the `errorContainer` configured, the code never reaches this point.

PS Really like how you can debug using the console.log in the run snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#login-form").validate({
  rules: {
   username:{
    required:true,
    normalizer:function(value){
     return $.trim(value);
    },
    email:true,
   },
   password:{
    required:true,
    normalizer:function(value){
     return $.trim(value);
    },
    minlength:8
   },
   
  },
  errorContainer: "#errorMessageContainer",
  errorLabelContainer: "#errorMessageContainer ul",
  errorElement: "li",
  messages: {
   username:{
    required:"Email cannot be left empty",
    email:"Must be an Email address"
   },
   password: {
    required: "Password Cannot Be Left Empty",
    minlength: "Password must contain 8 characters"
   }
  }
  ,
  invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            //Can something be done here?
            console.log('invalidContainer');
  },
  submitHandler: 
   function(form) {
    form.submit();
   }
 });
 
 displayErrorContainer();
   
});


function displayErrorContainer(){
 var child = $("#errorMessageContainer").children("ul").html();
 console.log('ftn: msg displayErrorContainer:'+child);
 if(typeof child !== "undefined" && child.length > 0){
  //console.log("show the error-container");
  $("#errorMessageContainer").show();
 }else{
  //console.log("hide the error-container");
  $("#errorMessageContainer").hide();
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->

<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<div id="errorMessageContainer">
  <ul><li>Username and Password do not match</li></ul>
</div>
<form id="login-form" request="POST">
 <input id="username" name="username"  type="text" />
 <input id="password" name="password"  type="password" />
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The `invalidHandler` fires when two conditions are met... 1.  The submit button is pressed and 2.  the form contains any invalid field.  There is nothing about the `errorContainer` option that would block this.

Comment: @Sparky I thought maybe the invalidHandler would be the answer I was looking for. Is there another technique in which this method can be applied? For instance, if a field is valid, is there a function that can possibly interrupt the flow to keep the server error from disappearing as in the steps I have detailed above. I really do appreciate you taking the time to reply. :)

Comment: Your request is still unclear.  However, you can possibly leverage the `success` option.  It's the option that is used to show the error label object when the field is valid, as opposed to invalid.  However, you'd have to manually populate it with a message.

Comment: I'll look into the success option tmw morning. I was hoping my steps above would clearly state what I was trying to achieve. :) I am being picky about the server error message disappearing and reappearing again. This is due to the validation of the form, which changes the visibility of the error container. :)

Comment: I should have stated that it was "unclear to me", simply because I did not take the time to examine your spec.  Meanwhile, I think the `success` option will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Side tracked at the moment but will look into this eventually and I think you've nailed it down. :)